# Gradle Java Custom Plugin: find URL of a dependency and recursiverly all the ones it depends on

Tags: java, maven, plugins, gradle

I am creating a Gradle plugin (Y) in Java that is equivalent to a Maven one I previously implemented. Given a dependency (X) of the plugin (Y), I need to find its URL and the URL of all the dependencies X depends on. This is needed to create a full classpath for X (which is a Java application) to execute it on a new JVM/process.

In a Maven plugin, this is achieved with:

```
//injected objects
//@Parameter(defaultValue = "${plugin.artifacts}", required = true, readonly = true)
//private List<Artifact> artifacts;
//@Component
//private ProjectBuilder projectBuilder;
//@Parameter(defaultValue="${repositorySystemSession}", required = true, readonly = true)
//private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;

// first find the artifact, ie the jar of the dependency
Artifact x = null;  
for(Artifact art : artifacts){
    if(art.getArtifactId().equals("name-of-the-X-artifact")){
        x = art;
        break;
    }
}

/*
 * build a project descriptor for the artifact, which is needed to
 * query all of its dependencies 
 */
DefaultProjectBuildingRequest req = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest();
req.setRepositorySession(repoSession);       
req.setValidationLevel(ModelBuildingRequest.VALIDATION_LEVEL_MINIMAL);
req.setSystemProperties(System.getProperties());
req.setResolveDependencies(true);   

ProjectBuildingResult res = projectBuilder.build(x, req);

// finally, determine the full classpath
String cp = x.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
for(Artifact dep  : res.getProject().getArtifacts()){
    cp += File.pathSeparator + dep.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

How to achieve the same in Gradle? Given:

```
public class MyPluginY implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  public void apply(Project p) {        
  }
}
```

I can iterate through its dependencies with `for(Configuration c : p.getBuildscript().getConfigurations())` and then `for(Dependency d: c.getAllDependencies())`. However:

1. How to determine the URL of `d`?
2. How to recursively find all the dependencies of `d`?

Comment: for 2. I did something similar in a plugin I wrote some time ago. You might want to have a look at https://github.com/NullStress/gradle-dependency-analysis-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/nullstress/tasks/AnalyzeTask.groovy and https://github.com/NullStress/gradle-dependency-analysis-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/nullstress/ArtifactResolver.groovy

Comment: Any update for (1)? I can't find any reference to do this. The only clue I found is [DependencyArtifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencyArtifact.html) but I can't find a way to get that object.